# Binding data in created dropdown from ajax data

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following dropdown created in cshtml page:

```
@(  Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("ddlCode").OptionLabel("Select Code...").BindTo(@ViewBag.dropDown)
            .DataTextField("Title")
            .DataValueField("domainCode")
```

I am binding this dropdown on checking of oneof the checkbox on my page.

On checking of checkbox i have called javascript function and written ajax script as follows:

```
var ddl = $('#ddlCode').data("kendoDropDownList");
            $.ajax({
                url: "/PP/BindDropDown",
                data: {
                    'Id': paramID
                },
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                success: function (_data) {

                    ddl.dataSource.data(_data)

                },
                error: function () {
                    //
                }
            });
```

BindDropdown of PPController contains code as:

```
public JsonResult BindDropDown(string ID)
        {
            List<TEAMS_PP.Entity.correlations> list = new correlation().getDropDownvalues(ID);
            ViewBag.dropDown = list;
            return Json(list);
        }
```

My problem is when dropdown gets bound it shows its items as "`Undefined`" as below:

[image]

How can i bind this dropdown???

I am using MVC4 Kendo UI Controls

Entity.Correlations:

```
   public correlations() { }

    public correlations(DB.EH_PP_DmainComp item)
    {
        //this.code = Convert.ToInt32( Convert.ToString(item.domainCode));
        this.correlatedText = item.description;
        this.codeTitle = item.title;
        //Component 1a: Demonstrating Knowledge of Content and Pedagogy
        //ArrayList arrCode = new ArrayList();
        string[] arrCode = Convert.ToString(item.title).Split(':');

        string[] code = Convert.ToString(arrCode[0]).Split(' ');
        this.code = Convert.ToString(code[1]);

    }

    public DB.EH_PP_DmainComp ToDB()
    {
        var rec = new DB.EH_PP_DmainComp();

        return rec;
    }

    public DB.EH_PP_DmainComp ToDB(DB.EH_PP_DmainComp rec)
    {

        return rec;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `TEAMS_PP.Entity.correlations`?

Comment: That is just a class to assign properties

Comment: @Leo I have updated it in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that here...

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("ddlCode").OptionLabel("Select Code...").BindTo(@ViewBag.dropDown)
        .DataTextField("Title")
        .DataValueField("domainCode")
```

You are telling the `DropDownList` to find the `Title` and the `domainCode` property in the `correlations` class. However, the `correlations` class does NOT have such properties.

To make this work you have to do one of the followings:

1. Add a `Title` and `domainCode` property to the `correlations` class
2. Use a different model object that exposes this property so that the dropdown list can bind to it

Comment: Thanx, this was the exact solution :)